# jQuery Validation Plugin - How to show labels on page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

The plugin inserts a label when a input has been filled out, however I want all the labels to be inserted on page load. Any ideas would be great, thanks.

The link to the plugin is here.

http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

I'm thinking there is a method I can use to just insert all the labels.

An example of the code would be as follows.

On page Load a field might look like this...

```
<div id="name-field" class="field input-text">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'Name'" onfocus="if (this.value=='Name') this.value = ''" value="Name" class="requiredAstrix" />
    <div id="name-error-label" class="error-label f3a cf98">
    This field is required
    <div class="arrow s14"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="name-hover-label" class="hover-label cf2"></div>
</div>
```

Onblur the plugin inserts a label as per below... (this is how I want all the fields to be on page load)

```
<div id="name-field" class="field input-text">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'Name'" onfocus="if (this.value=='Name') this.value = ''" value="Name" class="requiredAstrix" />
    <label for="name" class="error checked">&nbsp;</label>
    <div id="name-error-label" class="error-label f3a cf98">
    This field is required
    <div class="arrow s14"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="name-hover-label" class="hover-label cf2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I have tried to explain a bit better!

Comment: Where is your _jQuery_ code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [the `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) to perform the validation test programatically on DOM ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('name-field').validate({  // initialize the plugin on your form
        // rules,
        // messages,
        // options,
        // callback functions
    });

    $('name-field').valid();   // immediately fire validation on DOM ready

});
```

**Working DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/JVzKd/